# Switch between generic and xanmod kernel

Tags: 20.04, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I have recently installed xanmod kernel, however, I wanted to change back to generic kernel. How can I do that?

The output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`:

```
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic               5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-31-generic               5.0.0-31.33~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic               5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-36-generic               5.0.0-36.39~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic               5.0.0-37.40~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic               5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic               5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic               5.3.0-40.32~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic               5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic               5.3.0-45.37~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic               5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic               5.3.0-51.44~18.04.2                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-59-generic               5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic               5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic               5.4.0-45.49                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic               5.4.0-47.51                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic               5.4.0-48.52                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic               5.4.0-51.56                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic               5.4.0-52.57                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic               5.4.0-53.59                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic               5.4.0-54.60                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic               5.4.0-56.62                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic               5.4.0-58.64                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.16-xanmod1                 5.8.16-xanmod1-0~git20201018.dc69f04  amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.8.16-xanmod1
rc  linux-image-5.8.5-xanmod1                  5.8.5-xanmod1-0~git20200827.65efbed   amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.8.5-xanmod1
rc  linux-image-5.9.11-xanmod1                 5.9.11-xanmod1-0~git20201125.23f9b7a  amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.9.11-xanmod1
ii  linux-image-5.9.13-xanmod2                 5.9.13-xanmod2-0~git20201208.4d5bf39  amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.9.13-xanmod2
ii  linux-image-5.9.14-xanmod1                 5.9.14-xanmod1-0~git20201212.991c8eb  amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.9.14-xanmod1
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.4.0.58.61                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Generic kernels are still in my system, just not "activated".

I've tried `apt remove linux-image-5.9.14-xanmod1`, but the result is just falling back to `linux-image-5.9.13-xanmod2`.

I've also edited `/etc/default/grub` to have this line `GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-5.4.0-58-generic-advanced-b813c97f-cc0b-4c15-90de-e2fd416fd68e'`, but it doesn't make any difference.

How can I uninstall xanmod and use generic kernels?

Answer (score 0):

You have Ubuntu kernels installed. Boot to an Ubuntu kernel using grub menu and remove all xanmod kernel images with synaptic.

You need to remove them all, not the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how to boot into grub menu? I don't see that during my boot process

Comment: Press ESC or Shift on boot. If you remove all xanmod kernels, the system will boot into Ubuntu kernels anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and added `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` to my `/etc/default/grub`, so it would use whatever kernel I chose last.

I am using ZFS root, so it helps to keep a few kernels around in case a new one doesn't boot the system for some reason...

Here's the `head` of the file so you can see it for an example:

```
# head -n 10 /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on iommu=pt intremap=no_x2apic_optout transparent_hugepage=always vfio-mdev=on"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

I wouldn't keep as many kernels as you are, though.  That's pretty excessive.  I'm about to delete all but the newest `5-13.0-2x` packages when I'm done writing this.

```
# apt list --installed | grep linux-image | cut -d '/' -f1

linux-image-5.10.94-xanmod2
linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic
linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic
linux-image-5.13.0-29-generic
linux-image-5.15.0-18-generic
linux-image-5.15.17-xanmod2
linux-image-generic
```